# install opensuse: Brightness is too low and keyboard fn keys do not work

Tags: drivers, opensuse, keyboard, brightness

I installed OpenSUSE 13.1 in dual boot on my Samsung ATIV Book 6 pre-installed with Windows 8 with a USB key (ultrabook, no DVD reader at the moment).

**Brightness is too low and keyboard fn keys do not work**
while volume and touchpad-enable keys work. but not brightness or keyboard backlight.
I tried setting the brightness through command line with the commands `xrandr` and `xbacklight` but nothing happens, as advised in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625836/how-to-change-the-monitor-brightness-on-linux .

I used this tutorial http://tr.opensuse.org/SDB:Using_the_Extra_Keys_on_the_Keyboard to assign the variables XF86MonBrightnessUp (and others for keyboard) on available keyboard keys but once again nothing happens.

Comment: Please don't combine multiple issues in a single post. break them into separate questions instead.

Comment: Please break this Q up.

Comment: thank you for the post review, understood otherwise, I won't combine multiple issues in a single post and I therefore edited this one.

Comment: Ok, I discovered that if I plugged the computer, the brightness got higher. Same with the keyboard backlight that seems to adapt to the current luminosity. Since it's able to move, there must be a way to access it :). How to record such events in command line? that the brightness gets higher when i plugged out my laptop for example? Any ideas?